# Fileupload with javascript and php

Tags: javascript

When I use `fileupload`, I can't get path to work.
Path is show as `C:\fakepath\ram_education (2).sql` but it doesn't insert in the database

Here is my code:

```
function carrer()
{
    var name=document.careerfrm.name.value;
    var lname=document.careerfrm.lname.value;
    var email=document.careerfrm.email.value;
    var mobile=document.careerfrm.mobile.value;
    var currently=document.careerfrm.currently.value;
    var intrested=document.careerfrm.intrested.value;
    var city=document.careerfrm.city.value;
    var state=document.careerfrm.state.value;
    var zipcode=document.careerfrm.zipcode.value;
    var experience=document.careerfrm.experience.value;
    var resume=document.careerfrm.resume.value;

    url="career_db.php?name="+name+"&lname="+lname+"&email="+email+"&mobile="+mobile+"&currently="+currently+"&intrested="+intrested+"&city="+city+"&state="+state+"&zipcode="+zipcode+"&experience="+experience+"&resume="+resume;
    abc.open("GET",url,true);
    abc.send();
    alert(url);

    abc.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(abc.readyState==4)
        {
            document.getElementById('errorcarrer').innerHTML=abc.responseText;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the relation between the posted code and the fileupload? It sounds like a php issue instead of a javascript issue.

Comment: The javascript shown has no possibility of sending a file to the server, regardless of what's going on with the PHP. For starters, you need to be using a POST (or PUT) request instead of GET. You might find this reference useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects#Sending_files_using_a_FormData_object